# Angular directive not working with ng-container

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

The given below code ng-if is not working as expected

if `displayGroup` value is `D` then it will print the first and Second block, did I made any mistake

```
<div *ngIf="(bookTravelInfo.displayGroup | uppercase) === 'A' || 'B' || 'C'  ">
  <h2>Perfect!</h2>
</div>
<div *ngIf="(bookTravelInfo.displayGroup | uppercase) === 'D'  ">
  <h2>Does not Perfect</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check `bookTravelInfo.displayGroup` is either 'A' or 'B' or 'C',

Use

```
*ngIf="['A', 'B', 'C'].includes(bookTravelInfo.displayGroup | uppercase)"
```

`||` Logical OR operator from your `*ngIf` will never return `false`.

As the boolean result returned `true` when the value is neither `null`, nor `undefined` nor `false` as according to [ToBoolean](https://es5.github.io/#x9.2).

Hence the first `<div>` element still be displayed with:

```
*ngIf="(bookTravelInfo.displayGroup | uppercase) === 'A' || 'B' || 'C'"
```